# Having trouble outputting information from a text file

Tags: java

I'm having trouble finishing my assignment program for java class. Its supposed to show a menu then a sub-menu based on user selection and read in all info from a `.txt` file. It works with all animals and habitats selections except the first one...**"details on penguin habitat"**. If I edit the `.tx` file to show ".....habita" it works so removing the `T` makes a difference?

Can anyone take a look and help me see what I'm missing? Or maybe offer a workaround to get this selection to print?

Here is my code and text file info:

```
public class ZooInfo {

    public void zooDetails(String fileName) throws IOException {
         String fileInput = null;
         ArrayList aList1 = new ArrayList();

         int i = 0;
         int choice = 0;
         boolean loopExit = false;

         FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;                                                              // File input stream
        Scanner inFS = null;                                                                                // Scanner object
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\jrbla\\Desktop\\IT-145\\" + fileName + ".txt");    //open file
        inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

        while (inFS.hasNextLine() && loopExit == false) {
            fileInput = inFS.nextLine();

            if (fileInput.contains("Details on")) {
                i += 1;
                System.out.println(i + ". " + fileInput);

                ArrayList aList2 = new ArrayList();

                for (String retval : fileInput.split(" ")) {
                    aList2.add(retval);
                }

                String tempString = aList2.remove(2).toString();
                aList1.add(tempString);
            }
            else {
                if(choice != (i + 1)) {                                                               //while usr does not choose BACK
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.print("Choose details or enter " + (i + 1) + " to go back: ");
                    choice = scnr.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("");

                    if (choice <= i) {
                        String menuDetail = aList1.remove(choice - 1).toString();
                        outPut(fileName, menuDetail);
                        System.out.println("");

                    }
                    else if (choice == i + 1){
                        Main.mainMenu();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }    

        fileByteStream.close(); // Done with file, so try to close it
    }

    public void outPut(String fileName, String menuDetail) throws IOException {
        String fileInput = null;
        String lowerFileInput = null;
        String keeperAlert = "*****";
        String edFileInput = "";

        int fileNameLength = fileName.length();
        String lowerFileName = fileName.toLowerCase().substring(0, fileNameLength - 1);

        int menuDetailLength = menuDetail.length();
        String lowerMenuDetail = menuDetail.toLowerCase().substring(0, menuDetailLength - 1);

        boolean loopExit = false;

        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;                                                                  // File input stream
        Scanner inFS = null;                                                                                    // Scanner object
        fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\jrbla\\Desktop\\IT-145\\" + fileName + ".txt");        //try to open file
        inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

        while (inFS.hasNextLine() && loopExit == false) {
            fileInput = inFS.nextLine();
            lowerFileInput = fileInput.toLowerCase();

            if (lowerFileInput.contains(lowerFileName) && lowerFileInput.contains(lowerMenuDetail)) {
                do {
                    System.out.println(fileInput);
                    fileInput = inFS.nextLine();

                    if (fileInput.contains(keeperAlert)) {                                           //look for ALERT trigger
                        edFileInput = fileInput.replace(keeperAlert, "!! ZOOKEEPER ALERT !! ");
                        JFrame popUP = new JFrame();
                        popUP.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(popUP, edFileInput, "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

                    }

                    if (fileInput.isEmpty()) {
                       loopExit = true;
                    }
                }
                while (inFS.hasNextLine() && loopExit == false);
            }
        }

        fileByteStream.close();                                                 // Close file
    }
}
```

*Habitats.txt*

```
Details on penguin habitat  
Details on bird house  
Details on aquarium  

Habitat - Penguin  
Temperature: Freezing  
*****Food source: Fish in water running low  
Cleanliness: Passed  

Habitat - Bird  
Temperature: Moderate  
Food source: Natural from environment  
Cleanliness: Passed  

Habitat - Aquarium  
Temperature: Varies with output temperature  
Food source: Added daily  
*****Cleanliness: Needs cleaning from algae  



Selection 2 returns:  
Habitat - Bird  
Temperature: Moderate  
Food source: Natural from environment  
Cleanliness: Passed  

Selection 3 returns:  
Habitat - Aquarium  
Temperature: Varies with output temperature  
Food source: Added daily  
*****Cleanliness: Needs cleaning from algae  


but selection 1 returns incorrectly:  
Details on penguin habitat  
Details on bird house  
Details on aquarium
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not a minimum working example. If there is no problem with your "outPut" method, you don't need to include it... or you can include a simplified version of it. It doubles the size of your code and it makes it harder for people to help you.

Next, it is really difficult to see what you think you are trying to do, because you didn't comment your code at all, and it seems like you didn't have a plan to start with, and you just started typing up code. Consider writing some pseudo code first so that you can at least convince yourself, and possibly others, of your strategy.

You need to use better variable names. We can guess what you mean but that is annoying and wastes more time.

For example: you use "retval" to save the strings that are separated by spaces. If you had named the variable "word", it would make a lot more sense.

Similarly, you should have used better names for these:

"aList2" should be  "wordsOnLine"

"tempString" should be "habitatType"

"aList1" should be "habitatTypes"

I'm not sure what you intended "i" to mean... apparently, it is the number of habitats that you've declared at the top of your text file. You read the 3 "Details on" lines first, so when you move on to the remaining data, i will always be 3.

This doesn't seem to be useful for anything. It's always going to be 3, so when you get to the bottom of your method, you're not doing what you think you're doing... you're just comparing the user's choice to 3.

When the user enters choice = 1, you get into the first if() because:

```
choice != (i + 1)
1 != (3+1)
1 != 4
true
```

then you get into the next if() because:

```
choice <= i
1 <= 3
true
```

Now... you're doing strange things again. You are removing elements from your aList1, which is supposed to keep track of your habitat types. The list becomes shorter when you do this, and you no longer have any idea what's in the list or what the elements mean.

You need to plan your strategy better. Maybe this was a good first try, but you need to be more organized.

Comment: While these are perfectly valid comment it doesn't answer the question and this is not [codereview.se].

Comment: @user202729 that depends on what you think the question is. This question isn't actually a question. He only mentions that he's having trouble. He also asks "can anyone look [...] ?" but any sensible person will agree that the response he's looking for isn't "yes" .

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and solved it. The problem was this line:

if (lowerFileInput.contains(lowerFileName) && lowerFileInput.contains(lowerMenuDetail))

It's searching the text line for ("animal" or "habitat") and "habitat type" (ex. penguin).
The first text line has "details on penguin habitat" so it was triggering to print lines until a blank space. I solved it like this:

String redFlag = "details";

```
        if (lowerFileInput.contains(lowerFileName)&& lowerFileInput.contains(lowerMenuDetail) && !lowerFileInput.contains(redFlag)) {
```

so it skips the first lines containing "details" and returns the first section of Habitat - Penguin